# Microsoft Graph API: Getting the users who are assigned to a licence

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to get the users assigned to a licence trough the microsoft graph API. Much like on azure

[image]

Now thanks to the chrome devtools i found that the following api is called to get this information
https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/AccountSkus/UserAssignments

Unfortunately trying to access this api is convulted and definitely not suitable for production

I was wondering if there is a way something similar can be done trough the graph api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans
```

[image]

You can use the below query by  giving LastSignInDateTime and SKU to get the users for a particular assigned licenses  SKU

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-08-01T00:00:00Z&assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq xxx7a907fd6c235)&$select=displayname
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution using [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/).
The query you need to use is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/$count+ne+0&$count=true
```